# Series expansion of $\ln(1+\exp(ix))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am looking for a way to prove the following identity

$$\ln(1+\exp(ix))= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} \exp(inx)}{n} $$

What I know about the function is the given function is periodic with period $2 \pi$.
Can you give a hint on how to get this identity?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is not always true... at least for $x=0$.

Comment: But what if we consider $x>1 $? how to prove it?

Comment: For $x=\pi$ LHS is undefined.

Comment: For $|exp(ix)|=1$, the series does not converge absolutely.... that is, for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the Taylor's series of $\ln 1+z$ $$\ln(1+z)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} z^n}{n} $$and substituting back $z=\exp(ix)$.